Using React inside Stencil Tool web component
I have project which is using an older version of react and our team needs to use a library which requires a newer one. Since the project is too big to update it management has decided to use Web components. Hence the question: Can a web component (stencil tool) use a library which uses a new version of react while this component is embedded in another react (older version) app? I tried installing this proprietary library in a stencil tool starter component and it just can't resolve react despite it being in package.json and node_modules.
